# Using OpenIMAJ, which FaceAligner is suitable for constructing images that are used for eigenface?

Tags: face-recognition, brightness, eigenvector, openimaj

In order to calculate eigenfaces, Which FaceAligner is more suitable for constructing face images that better preserves the facial features?

The face images were not taken specifically for calculating eigenfaces, the face images are detected from normal photos. So the brightness of the face images are not at the same level, I wonder if there is a way to adjust the brightness of the images to the same level, or is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to experiment with the different aligners & see what works best in your images. You could call the `normalise()` method on each detected face image to remove global brightness variations, although this might not be strictly necessary with the Eigenfaces method (again, experimentation is needed).